# CSS: Android Web App: Color gradient issue

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am developing an Application with jQuery Mobile and Phonegap. I want to have a color gradient from #3c3c3c (grey) to #000000 (black) in the background but when I use this code

```
background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3c3c3c, #000000);
```

you can see just a few big bars with different grey shades. So there is no linear gradient. Also you are able to see some green and some violet bars.

```
  - Sorry as a new user I am not able to insert a Screenshot -
```

I also tried to instead insert a background image which shows a color gradient but this also looks as described above (we have also tried to maximize the color-depth of the picture but this also did not change the result).

Is it possible that the device is not able to display enough colors for a linear gradient? 
Is there another possibility for creating a linear gradient?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I am testing with
Galaxy Tab GT-P1000
Firmware-Version 2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cover all your bases:

```
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #3c3c3c), to( #000000)) !important; /* Saf4+, Chrome */
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#3c3c3c, #000000) !important; /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
        background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(#3c3c3c, #000000) !important; /* FF3.6 */
        background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(#3c3c3c, #000000) !important; /* IE10 */
        background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(#3c3c3c, #000000) !important; /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background-image:         linear-gradient(#3c3c3c, #000000) !important;
```

Drop the !important if you don't need it, I use it to override some default jQM styles that's why and make sure you have background-clip: border-box; (which is default)

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply! 
I tested it but the result was the same =/ 
I am still not able to post a screenshot here but I can send you a link to the jquery forum where I also posted this issue WITH a Screenshot ;-D 
Maybe that helps!

[link](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/help-color-gradient-issue)

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to write like this:

```
background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3c3c3c 0%, #000000 100%);
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer! 
But this code does work in - for example my chrome browser - but on the device i am testing nothing happens =/ 

I am testing with Galaxy Tab GT-P1000 Firmware-Version 2.2