# No CSS background gradients with Cordova

Tags: css, cordova

Somehow, I'm not able to render a background gradient in my Cordova project.

```
background: #f5a953;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5a953 0%, #fde1b2 49%, #f5a953 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5a953 0%,#fde1b2 49%,#f5a953 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5a953 0%,#fde1b2 49%,#f5a953 100%);
```

Gets me an empty plain white background on my mobile device.

- Changing `background` to `background-image` has no effect.
- Changing `background` to `background-color` at least makes the background be colored. But still no gradient. (That's likely to be the effect of the first line.)

How can I make the background of a Cordova project show a gradient?

**EDIT:**

I have now created a simple test project with `cordova create test` and then changed the css background to the following:

```
background-color: #fde1b2;
background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #fde1b2 0%, #f5a953 100%);
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #fde1b2 0%,#f5a953 100%);
background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #fde1b2 0%,#f5a953 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fde1b2', endColorstr='#f5a953',GradientType=1 );
```

chrome_desktop_view (correct)
[image: chrome_desktop_view (correct)]

chrome_mobile_view (correct)
[image: chrome_mobile_view (correct)]

galaxy_s6 Android 6.0.1 (wrong!)
[image: galaxy_s6 (wrong!)]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 linear-gradient not working on android.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536876/css3-linear-gradient-not-working-on-android)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264640/css-android-web-app-color-gradient-issue ---- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536876/css3-linear-gradient-not-working-on-android   Please Read these answers .

Comment: I found them both before asking this question and their solutions have no effect on my problem. Don't think I didn't search the web before.

Comment: Please develop a simple example by implementing both of these solutions for debugging purpose then test it .Then you can identify the issue . Thanks

Comment: I did. Both versions let my background stay plain white.
I found out that this seems to be a chrome problem. When I upload my www folder on a server and open the website with my mobile chrome browser, the same problem occurs. Is this a chrome bug??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by assigning the background gradient to a container div instead of the whole body.

**It seems like Chrome doesn't show background gradients that are assigned to the `<body>` tag.**

So I created a simple container div for which chrome bizarrely showed the background gradient.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    (nothing about the background)
}

div#container {
    background-color: #fde1b2;
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #fde1b2 0%, #f5a953 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #fde1b2 0%,#f5a953 100%);
    background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #fde1b2 0%,#f5a953 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fde1b2', endColorstr='#f5a953',GradientType=1 );
}
```